# Очистить TextField при переходе на новую страницу

Tags: flutter, uitextfield

Мне нужно очистить поле при переходе на следующую страницу, но при этом передать данные.
При такой записи поле видимо очищается раньше.
Как правильно это сделать?

```
Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          ConfirmationPurple(
                            username: dataController.text,
                            token: mainState.token,
                          ),
                    ),
                  );
                  dataController.clear();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Navigator.push` является асинхронным методом. Асинхронный метод помещается в очередь событий и вызывается только после выполнения всего синхронного кода. Поэтому вы можете очищать контроллер после закрытия страницы `СonfirmationPurple` т.е.

```
Navigator.push(...).then((_) => TextEditingController().clear());
```